# How does useState change even when it's a const?

Tags: reactjs, variables, constants, theory

I know that `const` can not be changed, how does declaring a `const [counter, setCouter] = useState();` still be able to change the `const counter` even though it's a `const`?

I came across [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) and variables inside different block scopes. But the `const counter` here works fine even though it's not in a different scope when you reassign it with `setCounter`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
function MyComponent() {
    const [state, setState] = useState("");
    return <SomeJsx/>;
}
```

When you call `setState`, the constant `state` does *not* change. Instead, `MyComponent` is called again, with `useState` now returning the updated value. This value is assigned to the `state` constant but this is part of a different function invocation, so it's actually not the same constant.

Answer (score 1):

well according to my understanding, in javascript const means you cannot re assign value to a variable using assignment operator and this is true with react state since state is immutable in react. you always need setState function to change it.

Comment: So the const is actually being variable shadowed aswell by useState()?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reassign `const` values in JavaScript and React doesn't do that either. What happens instead is each time the component is rendered, you get a new value and assign it to a **new** `const` variable. Components are functions that get called on rerenders, while React manages to handle unchanged and changed states so that resources are calculated economically. That is also the reason why **class components** can't use hooks, since classes aren't 'called' on every rerender.